# Force cv::Mat to use RGB data order

Tags: c++, opencv

By default `cv::imread` read data to `cv::Mat` in BGR order. I would prefer it in RGB order. Every time i read image I do a conversion:

```
cv::Mat image;
image = cv::imread("...",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
if(!image.data )
    ...
cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB);
```

is there a way to tell `Mat` or `imread` that colors order should be different?
Something like:

```
Cv::Mat image;
image.setOrder(CV_RGB) // ???
image = cv::imread("...",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, as a matter of fact, there is no such configurability of `imread()` or possibility to define a channel order.

I suggest you wrap your image reading and channel mixing in a small utility function.